# importing module

Tags: python, import

I'm using a virtualenv. (mentioned in case it matters)
My goal is to import TT.TruthTable into tests.
My hunch was to use `from lab import TT` as that statement mirrors one in a similar project/setup i'm working on. Could there be something else amiss.

```
lab03/
     lab/
        TT.py
        __init__.py
     test/
         tests.py
         __init__.py


>>> cat TT.py

    class TruthTable...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then `lab03/` (absolute path) should be added to your PYTHONPATH. Simply using a virtualenv isnt enough because it only sets up its own lib/python.x/site-packages in the path.

You can either modify your environment via: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/lab03`

Or, you can add it in code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/lab03")
from lab import TT
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds fine as long as lab03 is on your path.  This can either be done by:

a) executing the script from `lab03/` (`python test/tests.py`),

b) adding the directory to your `PYTHONPATH` (how to do this depends on your OS) prior to executing the program.

c) adding the directory to your `PYTHONPATH` before calling `from... import...`.  You can do this by appending the lab03 directory to your [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html).

I've done all 3, and prefer (c) then (a) then (b) but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a testing suite like [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/)? It can do all that for you, plus give you some easy options additional methods to use for testing. Plus, you can invoke it from your main project directory with `nosetests` and immediately get feedback.